# guava-libraries - Is the Ordering class thread safe?

Tags: java, static, thread-safety, guava

The [guava-libraries](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) have a class [Ordering](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release09/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html). I'm wondering if it's thread safe.

For example, can it be used as a static variable?

```
public static Ordering<String> BY_LENGTH_ORDERING = new Ordering<String>() {
   public int compare(String left, String right) {
      return Ints.compare(left.length(), right.length());
   }
};
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's as thread-safe as your `compare` method.

Default implementation of Ordering does not have any instance data, so the only thing that matters is how you define your compare method.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, `Ordering` objects are all immutable unless you do something to make them mutable, such as extending `Ordering` and adding mutable fields, or providing a mutable `Comparator` in the `from(Comparator)` method or a mutable `Function` in `onResultOf(Function)`.

But typically, you'd really have to go out of your way to make one that isn't thread safe.